# Concatenate shows the second and third value except the first value

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I have this macro that concatenates values from 3 cells, the problem is that it only concatenates the 1st and 2nd values, before it only concatenated the the first value was 3, the second value was march and the third value was 2015, so the result just gives me " 3march"

this is my code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Info").Activate

     Range("M2:Q2").Select
     Selection.Copy
     Range("A2").Cells(1).Select

     Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
  Selection.Offset(0, 12).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
       Selection.Offset(0, -12).Select
       Selection.Cells(1).Select


  'ahora viene la parte de pegar los valores,,,
  Selection.Cells(1).Value = TextBox1.Value
  Selection.Cells(1, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Value
  Selection.Cells(1, 3).Value = ComboBox4.Value
  Selection.Cells(1, 4).Value = ComboBox5.Value
  Selection.Cells(1, 5).Value = ComboBox6.Value
  Selection.Cells(1, 6).Value = ComboBox9.Value
   Selection.Cells(1, 7).Value = ComboBox13.Value
   Selection.Cells(1, 8).Value = TextBox3.Value
    Selection.Cells(1, 9).Value = TextBox4.Value
    Selection.Cells(1, 10).Value = TextBox8.Value
    Selection.Cells(1, 11).Value = TextBox6.Value
     Selection.Cells(1, 12).Value = ComboBox12.Value

     'HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!!
      f_env = Selection.Cells(1, 3).Value & "-" & Selection.Cells(1,          4).Value & "-" & Selection.Cells(1, 5).Value

         Selection.Cells(1, 17).Value = f_env



     Unload UserForm1
     End Sub
```

Comment: You're using the `Selection` object.  In VBA this is [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro -  Not necessarily in this context (assuming code is operating on the user's previously-selected range)

Comment: @TimWilliams, Even if it's based on the selection the selection should be set to another object.  It's basic OOP. And it makes the code more maintainable later if a good programmer takes over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Added new code.

It is hard to run the code as nobody but you has the workbook, and we would have to try and reproduce the workbook ourselves. Here is a revised code as I have interpreted what you are trying to do. I cannot test it as I don't have your workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Crng As Range    'copy range
    Dim LrWs As Long    'last row
    Dim Prng As Range    'paste range
    Dim Drng As Range
    Dim f_env As String

    Set sh = Worksheets("Info")

    With sh

        Set Crng = .Range("M2:Q2")
        LrWs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set Prng = .Cells(LrWs, 13)
        Crng.Copy
        Prng.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0

        Set Drng = .Cells(LrWs, 1)

        Drng.Value = TextBox1.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox4.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox5.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox6.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox9.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 6).Value = ComboBox13.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox3.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 8).Value = TextBox4.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 9).Value = TextBox8.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 10).Value = TextBox6.Value
        Drng.Offset(0, 11).Value = ComboBox12.Value

    End With

    f_env = ComboBox4.Value & "-" & ComboBox5.Value & "-" & ComboBox6.Value

    Drng.Offset(0, 16) = f_env

End Sub
```

Link us up to a sample workbook, if you can't get this working properly.

Comment: when I do it in a different macro it works for me too. please check my question again, y put my complete code. thanks

Comment: Added code, removing selects and using offsets. Play around with the offsets if they are not going in the correct locations.

Comment: It worked replacing the cells option with offset. thanks! what else could I use instead of select?

Answer (score 1):

Because the column (on the selection's row) is actually determined by the column that selection was in, you will get a date in column Q only if selection is in column A. That may be a minor point but I believe the destination should *always* be a certain column.

[image: Construct Date]

```
Sub gather_date()
    Dim sel As Range

    With Selection.Parent
        For Each sel In Selection.Columns(1).Cells
            If Application.CountA(sel.Resize(1, 3)) = 3 Then
                .Cells(sel.Row, 17) = CDate(Join(Array(sel.Value2, Left(sel.Offset(0, 1).Value2, 3), sel.Offset(0, 2).Value2), "-"))
                .Cells(sel.Row, 17).NumberFormat = "d-mmmm-yyyy"
            End If
        Next sel
    End With

End Sub
```

Since you are usig a macro based upon select, I've added a loop that will process all of the cells in selection.

This could also be performed with the following worksheet formula in Q2.

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(B2, "-", C2, "-", D2))
```

Format as a date and fill down as necessary.